# Sencha Touch 2 store php

Tags: javascript, php, sencha-touch-2

I want to fill a store with the result of a select from my db

My model is:

```
Ext.define('demoapp.model.CCAA',{
extend:'Ext.data.Model',
config:{
    fields:[{
        name:'id',
        type:'string'
    },
    {
        name:'nombre',
        type:'string'
    }]
}
});
```

My store is:

```
Ext.define('demoapp.store.CCAA',{
extend:'Ext.data.Store',
requires:['demoapp.model.CCAA'],
config:{
    storeId:'storeCCAA',
    autoLoad:true,
    model:'demoapp.model.CCAA',
    proxy:{
        type:'ajax',
        url:'here the url to your file(in my case a .php file)',
        reader:{
            root:'data'
        }
    }
}
});
```

And my php file:

```
<?php
include './config.php';

$sql="SELECT id,Autonomia from table";
$result= mysql_query($sql);
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
array_push($data, array(
        "id"                => $row["id"],
        "nombre"            => $row["Autonomia"],
));
}
echo json_encode(array(
    'data'=> $data,
    'success'=>true,
    'total'=>count($data)));

?>
```

I don't know how to continue declaring the store and fill it with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it.I edit the code with the solution.
And I load that store in a selectfield in a view.

In the app.js you load the store:

```
Ext.application({
    name:'demoapp',
    views:['Login','MainMenu'],
    controllers:['Login'],
    stores:['CCAA'],
    models:['CCAA'],
    launch:function(){
        Ext.Viewport.add([
            {xtype:'loginview'},
            {xtype:'mainmenuview'}
        ]);
        Ext.getStore('storeCCAA').load();
    }
});
```

And in the view you declare the selectfield:

```
items:[{
        xtype:'selectfield',
        itemId:'CCAAcombo',
        label:'Comunidad Autonoma',
        store:'storeCCAA',
        displayField:'nombre',
        valueField:'id',
}]
```